# Why this CSS settings is not applied at my tables?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I have the following CSS problem.

I have these 2 tables (the first one represent the header and the second one contains the content):

```
<div>
    <table border="1" class="standard-table-cls innerTable">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="14.2%">Codice RM</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Autore Firma</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Data Firma</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Acq Riserva</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Consegna Finale</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Descrizione RM</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Imponibile</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="overflowContainer">
    <table border="1" class="standard-table-cls innerTable scrollableTable">
        <tbody>
            <%
                int count = 0;
                for (RM currentRM : salDettaglio.getRM()) {
                    String test = currentRM.getAcqRiserva();
                    String evenOrOdd;
                    if((count & 1) == 0) {
                        evenOrOdd = "even";
                    }
                    else {
                        evenOrOdd = "odd";
                    }
                    count++;
                 %>

                 <tr id="rmRow" class=<%=evenOrOdd %> >
                     <td width="14.2%"><%=currentRM.getCodiceRm()%></td>
                     <td width="14.2%"><%=currentRM.getAutoreFirma()%></td>
                     <td width="14.2%"><%=currentRM.getDataFirma()%></td>
                     <td width="14.2%"><%=currentRM.getAcqRiserva()%></td>
                     <td width="14.2%"><%=currentRM.getConsegnaFinale()%></td>
                     <td width="14.2%"><%=currentRM.getDescrizioneRM()%></td>
                     <td width="14.2%"><%=currentRM.getImponibile().toString()%></td>
                  </tr>

            <%}%>
         </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Both the tables have setted the **standard-table-cls** and the **innerTable** classes.

This is the code of the **standard-table-cls** class:

```
table.standard-table-cls {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
    border : #76818a 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#76818a;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

And this is the code of the **innerTable** class (I want that a table that have the **innerTable** class setted have a width=70% of the total space and that it is floated on the right):

```
.innerTable{
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
}
```

The problem is that using the previous settings seems that don't see the CSS settings related to the **.innerTable** class.

The strange thing is that if I set the style inline, in this way:

```
<table border="1" class="standard-table-cls innerTable" style="width: 70%; float: right;">
```

it works.

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: [Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) is your problem.

Comment: Are you able to put this into a JSFiddle so I can fix it for you?

Comment: You can put header and content in a single table. That's the whole idea, I think, of having `th` and `td` elements.

Comment: @GolezTrol no because then I have to set the second table scrollable on the Y and using theader and tbody is a nightmare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table.standard-table-cls` styles are overriding you `.innerTable`.

For this, you should specify your styles like giving an id or using `!important`.

**1.** Using ID:

```
<table border="1" class="standard-table-cls" id="innerTable">
```

And CSS:

```
#innerTable{
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
}
```

**2.** Using `!important` (not the best way to do it though):

```
  .innerTable{
    width: 70% !important;
    float: right !important;
}
```

**Note:** You can use other ways of specifying yours elements.

You can see how to specify your elements through this chart:

[image]

Comment: Loving specificity wars.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
table.innerTable { }
```

**table.standard-table-cls** is more specific than **.innerTable**, so it overrides your style in **.innerTable**.

Answer (score 0):

probably is a problem of specificity: ["Specifics on CSS Specificity"](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

try:

```html
table.standard-table-cls {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border : #76818a 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#76818a;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.innerTable{
    width: 70% !important;
    float: right !important;
}
```